# OutOfMemoryError using Memcached

Tags: java, jvm, memcached, spymemcached

Im getting this error on a EJB with spymemcached, using memcached remote server running on wiwndows.

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:597)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.<init>(MemcachedConnection.java:132)
    at net.spy.memcached.DefaultConnectionFactory.createConnection(DefaultConnectionFactory.java:176)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.<init>(MemcachedClient.java:194)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.<init>(MemcachedClient.java:154)
```

Any idea about it? How can fix it?

Comment: Any idea about it? How can fix it?

Comment: You might want to give more detail about how it's configured.  It's kinda obvious to increase the memory used by the JVM, but that won't necessarily solve the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your probably doing async operations really fast and not checking the value for those operations. As a result the operations are queued up on the client until you run out of memory. Try calling the .get() function on your OperationFuture objects to make them synchronous.